# Interior and Closure of a set in a Cofinite Topology on R

Tags: general-topology

Considering the Cofinite Topology on Real Line

My question is what is the Closure and Interior of [a,b] with respect to this topology.

Actually I am a beginner. If you explain the underlying concept along with the answer to me then that would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: What are the open sets contained in $[a,b]$? What are the closed sets containing $[a,b]$?

Answer (score 1):

If $b>a$ then $[a,b]$ contains infinitely many elements, hence the only closed subset (in the cofinite topology) containing $[a,b]$ is $\Bbb R$ itself; it follows that the closure of $[a,b]$ is $\Bbb R$. Similarly for the interior. As $\Bbb R\setminus[a,b]$ contains infinitely many elements, the only open subset contained in $[a,b]$ is the empty set, hence $[a,b]^\circ=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

In this topology the open sets are very big, so let's try to keep this in mind when we are computating. I will denote the closure of $[a,b]$ as $\overline{[a,b]}$

Claim $\overline{[a, b]} = \mathbb{R}$, clearly $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ so let $x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } U \text{ an open set such that} x \in U$, now as $U$ is open $\mathbb{R}-U$ is finite and as $[a,b]$ is infinite then $ [a,b] \not\subset \mathbb{R}-U \Rightarrow\exists y \in [a,b] - (\mathbb{R}-U)$ then $y \in [a,b] \cap U \Rightarrow [a,b] \cap U \neq \emptyset$ so by definition $x \in \overline{[a,b]}$ this is true for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ so $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \overline{[a,b]}$ therefore we conclude $\overline{[a,b]} = \mathbb{R}$

With this in mind try to calculate the interior ¿Can $[a,b]$ contain any open set?

**Spoiler: int($[a,b]$) = $\emptyset$**